# MS SQL Server use old log file location after detach/copy/attach

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create database "Test" in folder "d:\test". Database files are "d:\test\Test.mdf" and "d:\Test\Test_log.ldf". I *detach* database from MS SQL Server 2008 R2, *copy* all files to new folder ("d:\test_new"), *delete log file* ("d:\test_new\Test_log.ldf"), and try to attach database again from new location. When I use SQL Server Management Studio, and choose "d:\test_new\Test.mdf" file, it determines that log file is located in "d:\test\Test_log.ldf" (old location). How can I attach this database with rebuilding log in new location? Just imagine, that I cannot copy ldf file again to new location, and that it is still available there, so SQL Server see it anyway. I want to say to SQL Server - "please, forget that log file, and create new log file here". It's be better if you help me with T-SQL script, but if it will be steps in Management studio - I will convert it to script myself.

What I had tried already:

1.

```
CREATE DATABASE [test] 
ON ( FILENAME = N'D:\test_new\test.mdf' ) 
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

attaches log file from old location (FOR ATTACH - the same)

2.

```
CREATE DATABASE [test] 
ON ( FILENAME = N'D:\test_new\test.mdf' ) 
LOG ON ( FILENAME = N'D:\test_new\test_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

returns an error: Unable to open the physical file "D:\test_new\test_log.ldf". Operating system error 2: "2(File not found.)".

3.

```
 sp_attach_db and sp_attach_single_file_db
```

was tried too. And I even had checked their source codes - they just create dynamic SQL and call CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH statement.

The question is slowly changed to: "Is it possible?"

#### UPDATE

Well, it looks like it's not possible with current versions of SQL Server. If anybody knows a way to do it - please, I will be very pleased to know it too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2**: To my knowledge, it is not possible for SQL Server to recreate a log file. It can shrink the ldf, but not create it when only the mdf exists.

---

When you copy your files from `d:\test\` to `d:\test_new\`, **do not delete** the `d:\test_new\Test_log.ldf`.

Leave the log file there, because you cannot reattach the new DB without that log file. Afterwards, you can shrink that log to a minimum size.

So, to synthesize:

1. Copy your files from `d:\test\` to `d:\test_new\` and leave the log
   file there.
2. Run your `create database` script that you posted in your question (point 2).
3. Run the following script to shrink the log to a minimum size

.

```
USE test
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(logicalFileName, 1)
GO
```

To find out what `logicalFileName` is, run `sp_helpfile`, that will give you the logical file name for your log file:

```
USE test
GO
EXEC sp_helpfile
GO
```

more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)

**Edit:**
I think you need first to detach the `test` database from the old location:

(You might create a script that does it all, from the following commands)

```
C:\> osql -E 
1> sp_detach_db 'test'
2> go 
3> quit 
C:\>
```

Then copy the files to the new location.

```
C:\> copy d:\test\* d:\test_new\*
```

Next, attach the `test` DB to the new path location:

```
C:\> osql -E 
1> sp_attach_db @dbname = N'test', @filename1 = N'd:\test_new\Test.mdf', @filename2 = N'd:\test_new\Test_log.ldf' 
2> go 
3> quit 
C:\>
```

to test if the new database was successfully attached:

```
C:\> osql -E 
1> use test
2> go 
3> quit 
C:\>
```

If there are no errors after the `go` command, then all is ok

Hope this helps

[Microsoft article on how to move files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071)

Comment: The problem is that all this actions are done not with my hands, but with users' :) I know, that log file should be copied too. I just describe one of the real situation from my customer (well, actually user didn't delete log file, he didn't copy it to new location. But the result is the same - in the old folder there are mdf and ldf file, and in the new - only mdf file). If old ldf file is not available - everything is OK, MS SQL server just recreate it in new location.

Comment: But imagine, that you have ported your old application from Access database to MS SQL Server. Users are used to copy access database, rename it, and open in application again. And they have now 2 different databases. They want to have the same simple way to play with MS SQL Server, but they have not DBA. They are *users*. And very often users know about mdf file, but they don't know anything about ldf file.. I think we will add copy/rename functionality to our custom "sqlmanagement" solution, but in general - how to fix this issue?

Comment: You can attach files from new location with old database name. You can try to execute your example with sp_attach_db with database name "test" - everything will work right. But only if there is log file. But, as I said, log file is in old folder.. And this way you can use only sp_attach_single_file_db, and this sp will use old log file. Well, it looks like this problem has not solution :(

Comment: I have edited once again. You need to detach the `test` from the old location, otherwise SQL server will still look for data and log files in `d:\test\`

Comment: I know right way to make a copy or move database to new location. Of course, test database wass detached from SQL Server before. The problem is not *how to move database to new location*, the problem is *how to attach right way mdf file from new location, if log file is not presented in new folder, but is presented in old folder*. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answers and time.

Comment: Isn't more easy to tell the users, that SQL server is different from Access, and that they need to copy the log file as well? I guess this simple rule, solves the whole problem.

Comment: Yes, as I said, for now we decide to add "copy database" feature to our custom SqlManagement application. And for now the problem is removed. But the question is keeped in mind, just as "sporting interest" - is it possible in MS SQL Server? If "NO" - it's ok too. Just "sporting interest".

Comment: can you please write in the beginning of your answer that it's impossible to do with current versions of SQL Server, so I could mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The users must copy BOTH the .mdf and .ldf files. They then have to use the following command (one or the other).

**sp_attach_db (deprecated, use the CREATE DATABASE WITH ATTACH in the future)**

EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = 'dbname', @filename1='d:\test_new\test.mdf', @filename2='d:\test_new\test.ldf'

This will result in the databas using the data file (mdf) and transaction log (ldf) from the \test_new directory

**CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH**

CREATE DATABASE dbname ON '(FILENAME=d:\test_new\test.mdf'), (FILENAME='d:\test_new\test.ldf') FOR ATTACH

Comment: If you will read my question, you can understand, that I KNOW about all this variants and I TRIED them. I have one concrete question - about attaching .mdf file after moving it to another directory, without .ldf file. Please, read question carefully before answering.